# How to display radio buttons as <div>

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I want to display my radio buttons as  so that i can give style sheet and make `div` clickable.

here are my radio buttons.

[image]

and I want to show them like this.

**div as radio**

[image]

This is what I have tried but did not work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" id="radioone" name="product" value="first">
                <label for="radioone">50</label></td>

            <td><input type="radio" id="radiotwo" name="product" value="second">
                <label for="radiotwo">100</label></td>

            <td><input type="radio" id="radiothree" name="product" value="third">
                <label for="radiothree">500</label></td>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.radio-toolbar input[type='radio']:focus + label {
  border: 2px thin blue;
}
.radio-toolbar input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  background-color: #86b1f7;
  border-color: #4c4;
  color: white;
}
```

So how can I achive this 
Small help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had do this before.and I have the code preperd.I hope It will be useful for you.

```css
.switch-field {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    direction: ltr;
    float: right;
    text-align:right;
}

.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
    /*width: 33.33%;*/
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    /*margin-right: -1px;*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: #F4F5F9;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: #3E7DE7;
    color: #3E7DE7;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
    border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;

}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
    border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;

}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field">
  <input class="uk-radio" id="radio-six" type="radio" value="admin" name="user_type" checked>
  <label for="radio-six">admin</label>
   <input class="uk-radio" id="radio-seven" type="radio" value="user" name="user_type" >
   <label for="radio-seven">user</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can customize your radio buttons.

```css
.radio-toolbar .radio-item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 15px 5px;
}

.radio-item input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.radio-item label {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.radio-item input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-toolbar">
  <div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="radioone" name="product" value="first">
    <label for="radioone">50</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="radiotwo" name="product" value="second">
    <label for="radiotwo">100</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-item">
    <input type="radio" id="radiothree" name="product" value="third">
    <label for="radiothree">500</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the radio buttons and the left over label is still "clickable"

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

I put all the working code on codepen here: https://codepen.io/stormingorman-the-vuer/pen/ExjKRvz

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This. Make Your **radio-toolbar input**, `width: 0;`

also make your **radio-toolbar label** Like this

```
.radio-toolbar label {

    background-color: #A9A9A9;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```